# AWS Cognito RedirectMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate cognito with my app but when trying to access the ip of the instance with the user-pool configured I get the following error: An error was encountered with the requested page.

Here is the error my URL gives.
https://my-domain/error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=(client ID)

Looks like this is a callback URL issue but can't seem to figure out why.
My sign in/out callback URL's are currently:
https:ec2-ip/auth/sign_in and sign_out respectively.

The app is currently being run using multiple docker containers which are hosted on a ec2.

I have listed the relevant pieces of code and any help would be much appreciated.

- **Auth_Controller.rb**

```
def signin
    unless params[:code]
      render :nothing => true, :status => :bad_request
      return
    end

    resp = lookup_auth_code(params[:code])
    unless resp
      redirect_to '/'
      return
    end

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      user = User.where(subscriber: resp.id_token[:sub]).first
      if user.nil?
        user = User.create(subscriber: resp.id_token[:sub],
                           email: resp.id_token[:email])

          render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/user_taken.html", layout: false
          return
        end
      end

      cognito_session = CognitoSession.create(user: user,
                                              expire_time: resp.id_token[:exp],
                                              issued_time: resp.id_token[:auth_time],
                                              audience: resp.id_token[:aud],
                                              refresh_token: resp.refresh_token)
      session[:cognito_session_id] = cognito_session.id
    end
  end

  def signout
    if cognito_session_id = session[:cognito_session_id]
      cognito_session = CognitoSession.find(cognito_session_id) rescue nil
      cognito_session.destroy if cognito_session
      session.delete(:cognito_session_id)
    end

    session[:current_queries] = nil

    redirect_to '/'
  end

  def lookup_auth_code(code)
    client = new_cognito_client()
    client.get_pool_tokens(code)
  end
end
```

- **Session_Controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :redirect_to_signin
  def signin
    redirect_to cognito_signin_url
  end

  def signout
    redirect_to cognito_signout_url
  end

  def signup
    redirect_to cognito_signup_url
  end

private

  def cognito_signin_url
    CognitoUrls.login_uri(ENV['AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID'],
                          signin_redirect_uri)
  end

  def cognito_signup_url
    CognitoUrls.signup_uri(ENV['AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID'],
                           signin_redirect_uri)
  end

  def cognito_signout_url
    CognitoUrls.logout_uri(ENV['AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID'],
                           signout_redirect_uri)
  end

  def signin_redirect_uri
    auth_sign_in_url
  end

  def signout_redirect_uri
    auth_sign_out_url
  end
end
```

- **Routes.rb:**

```
require 'sidekiq/web'
require 'sidekiq/cron/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/sign_in', as: 'signin', to: 'sessions#signin'
  get '/sign_out', as: 'signout', to: 'sessions#signout'
  get '/sign_up', as: 'signup', to: 'sessions#signup'

  get 'auth/sign_in', to: 'auth#signin'
  get 'auth/sign_out', to: 'auth#signout'
```

- **Cognito_URL.rb**

```
class CognitoUrls
  AUTHORIZE_PATH = "/oauth2/authorize"
  TOKEN_PATH = "/oauth2/token"
  LOGIN_PATH = "/login"
  LOGOUT_PATH = "/logout"
  SIGNUP_PATH = "/signup"

  class << self
    @base_oauth_uri = nil
    @base_idp_uri = nil

    def init(domain, region)
      @base_oauth_uri = ENV['OAUTH_URL']
      # @base_oauth_uri = "https://%s.auth.%s.amazoncognito.com" % [domain, region]
      @base_idp_uri = "https://cognito-idp.%s.amazonaws.com" % [region]
    end

    def jwks_uri(pool_id)
      path = "/%s/.well-known/jwks.json" % [pool_id]
      URI.join(@base_idp_uri, path).to_s
    end

    def refresh_token_uri
      @base_idp_uri
    end

    def authorize_uri
      URI.join(@base_oauth_uri, AUTHORIZE_PATH).to_s
    end

    def token_uri
      URI.join(@base_oauth_uri, TOKEN_PATH).to_s
    end

    def force_https(url)
      uri = URI.parse(url)
      uri.scheme = "https"
      uri.to_s
    end

    def login_uri(app_client_id, redirect_uri)
      if Rails.env == 'production'
        redirect_uri = force_https(redirect_uri)
      end
      path = "%s?response_type=code&client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s" %
        [LOGIN_PATH, app_client_id, redirect_uri]
      URI.join(@base_oauth_uri, path).to_s
    end

    def logout_uri(app_client_id, redirect_uri)
      if Rails.env == 'production'
        redirect_uri = force_https(redirect_uri)
      end
      path = "%s?response_type=code&client_id=%s&logout_uri=%s" %
        [LOGOUT_PATH, app_client_id, redirect_uri]
      URI.join(@base_oauth_uri, path).to_s
    end

    def signup_uri(app_client_id, redirect_uri)
      if Rails.env == 'production'
        redirect_uri = force_https(redirect_uri)
      end
      path = "%s?response_type=code&client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s" %
        [SIGNUP_PATH, app_client_id, redirect_uri]
      URI.join(@base_oauth_uri, path).to_s
    end
  end
end
```

I was expecting to be taken to the Cognito login page.

Comment: This is not a code error -- this is a configuration error. Does the redirect_uri parameter in the request to the Cognito endpoint match the "Callback URL" found in the Cognito user pool's App client settings?

Comment: To add to what dbugger said, it has to match EXACTLY. https if it's https, same domain, same path, even the trailing slash can throw off some implementations. You obfuscated your example, but I see you use `my-domain` in one example and `ec2-ip` in the second one.

Comment: Hi Both, Thanks for your answers. I am confused as to where the re-direct URL is being called from within my code and thus am not sure what the callback URL should be then. Would you be able to advise based on the code above?